# Android : Upload multiple files showing Progress Bar in percentage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want show Progress Bar when uploading multiple images in Firebase database.

```
.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                            Log.e("progresse", "==" + progress);


                        }
                    });
```

It's good for when upload one image ,i want show percentage when upload 3 images.

Comment: post your full code.

Comment: i just used for loop.uploading the file

Comment: how are you getting firebase response? you can do it with `RecyclerView` add your all downloads in a list and update it every time.